# How to generate error bars to the upper and lower by groups in R ggboxplot?

Tags: r, rstudio, boxplot

I am trying to create a grouped box plot with 'star' symbol using R `ggboxplot`. However, I am having difficulties adding error bar, especially with upper and lower horizontal lines. Here is my code and the output.

```
library(ggpubr)
library("ggsignif")
s=15
p <- ggboxplot(data, x = "MRI", y = "featurevalue",
               color = "black",fill="filename",palette = "aaas",
               notch = TRUE,outline=FALSE,
               font.x = s,font.y = s,
               font.xtickslab = s,font.ytickslab = s,
               font.legend = s,
               legend.title="",
               ylim = c(0, 1.04))
p + 
  stat_compare_means(size=8,aes(group = filename),label = "p.signif",hide.ns = TRUE,method = "t.test") + 
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(fill='transparent',color='black')) + 
  theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill="transparent",colour="black"), 
  legend.position=c(0.85,0.93),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  legend.margin=margin(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), unit='cm'),
  legend.key = element_blank(),
  plot.margin=unit(c(0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1),'lines'))
```

Someone said that use `ggplot2` will have error bars automatically. But I can not able to add the 'star' symbol with `ggplot2`. I have tried to use `error.plot = c("upper_errorbar", "lower_errorbar")` in `ggboxplot` in order to add error bar, but this command seems not used for grouped boxplot, I showed the figure I get below. Is there a correct way to combine this commend and `add.params = list(group=)`, in order to generate grouped error bars?

[image]

Could anyone help in generating error bars in grouped boxplots? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the "error bar" parameter inside the ggboxplot() function?

```
bxp.errorbar = TRUE
```

Give the above parameter inside ggboxplot() function and check.